# Protobuf over zeromq/zwssock to JSMQ/ProtoBuf.js messages are not fully recieved

Tags: javascript, c, protocol-buffers, zeromq

I'm sending Protobuf encoded data over zwssock (czmq) -- which is an websocket extension for zcmq -- to JSMQ.js after which the decoding of the protobuf data takes place.

1. OS: Windows
2. Browser: Chrome 40.0.2
3. ØMQ: 4.0.4
4. czmq: 2.2.0.

With the following problem:

the data recieved does not contain all bytes that have been send.
In fact after inspection it turns out that all bytes where recieved up to the first 0 byte.

Real example:

data send:

> 10,4,78,77,69,65,-110,3,19,8,101,-86,6,14,8,1,16,-40,-126,-27,-14,-12,-87,-61,2,
>   -16,1,1,-110,3,93,8,100,80,0,-94,6,86,34,73,36,71,80,82,77,67,44,49,48,51,50,51,
>   49,46,54,48,49,44,86,44,53,50,48,53,46,54,52,50,54,55,48,44,78,44,48,48,54,49,57
>   ,46,54,49,51,57,52,55,44,69,44,52,51,46,50,44,51,54,46,52,44,50,51,48,49,49,53,4
>   4,44,44,83,42,54,68,32,74,9,69,80,83,71,58,52,51,50,54,-30,3,97,10,4,78,77,69,65
>   ,18,73,36,71,80,82,77,67,44,49,48,51,50,51,49,46,54,48,49,44,86,44,53,50,48,53,4
>   6,54,52,50,54,55,48,44,78,44,48,48,54,49,57,46,54,49,51,57,52,55,44,69,44,52,51,
>   46,50,44,51,54,46,52,44,50,51,48,49,49,53,44,44,44,83,42,54,68,32,82,14,10,5,8,2
>   ,-80,1,2,-94,6,4,8,8,16,6

data recieved:

> 0, 10, 4, 78, 77, 69, 65, 146, 3, 19, 8, 101, 170, 6, 14, 8, 1, 16,
>   137, 255, 156, 213, 244, 169, 195, 2, 240, 1, 1, 146, 3, 93, 8, 100,
>   80]

As you can see the byte after 80 is missing, and the squence now start with a 0 byte. I've tested with manually created data -- char* --, and everytime the same problem would occur.

The two functions below are directly taken from JSQM.js and are called by the websocket upon data recieved.

```
 function onmessage(ev) {
        if (ev.data instanceof Blob) {
            var arrayBuffer;
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = function () {
                processFrame(this.result);
            };
            fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(ev.data);
        } else if (ev.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            processFrame(ev.data);
        }
        // Other message type are not supported and will just be dropped
    };

    function processFrame(frame) {
        var view = new Uint8Array(frame);
        var more = view[0];

        if (incomingMessage == null) {
            incomingMessage = new JSMQ.Message();
        }

        incomingMessage.addBuffer(frame);

        // last message
        if (more == 0) {
            if (that.onMessage != null) {
                that.onMessage(that, incomingMessage);
            }

            incomingMessage = null;
        }
    }
```

In the onmessage/processFrame the received data already does not contain the full bytes sequence. As you can see the received byte sequence starts with a 0, matching the [more == 0] guard.

I was not able to get wireshark to sniff the packages send, checking
if the bytes where not correctly send.

One solution would be to use bytestuffing thus removing all 0 bytes.
But surely I've must have made a mistake somewhere?

As requested:

Internally we use the c++ library of zeromq, however since the websockets 
are currently een extention on the c version we need to convert to c style message. As mentioned the data has been stuffed.

```
void CZeroMQConnection::Send(zmq::message_t& message)
{

    zmsg_t* msg = zmsg_new();

    std::vector<unsigned char> rpl;
    std::copy_n(reinterpret_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size(),std::back_inserter(rpl));

    // Temporary stuffing on Websockets
    char stuffChar = 1;
    char invalidChar = 0;

    std::vector<unsigned char> stuffed;
    for (auto it = rpl.begin(); it != rpl.end(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == invalidChar || *it == stuffChar)
        {
            stuffed.push_back(stuffChar);
            stuffed.push_back((*it) + 1);
        }
            else
                stuffed.push_back(*it);
        }

    // As mentioned added extra 0 byte, preventing superfluos data
    stuffed.push_back(0);
    zmsg_push(msg, _id);
    zmsg_addstr(msg, reinterpret_cast<char*> (&stuffed[0]));
    zwssock_send(_socket, &msg);
}
```

There is is not yet a bi-directional dataflow, this will come in the near future.

Comment: is happening in both ways or only from zeromq to jsmq?

Comment: are you sending multi part message? can you add the code using the zwssock?

Comment: @somdoron i'm not able to access the src before tuesday, ill send example as soon as i can. I saw that a fix for the leading 0 byte had already been proposed. I did perform the byte-stuffing and was able to get all the data, however i had to add an additional 0 byte at the end of my buffer since i was getting way too much data on the recieving end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you somdoron,

your post uses:

```
zmsg_addmem(msg, buf, 226);
```

while i was using:

```
zmsg_addstr(msg, reinterpret_cast<char*> (&stuffed[0]));
```

which will probably interpret the input as a C string.

This solved the problem, thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce the issue with chrome (40.0.2) without success, I got the entire message including the zeros.

c code:

```
static char *listen_on = "tcp://127.0.0.1:86";

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    zctx_t *ctx;
    zwssock_t *sock;

    char *l =  argc > 1 ? argv[1] : listen_on;

    ctx = zctx_new();
    sock = zwssock_new_router(ctx);

    zwssock_bind(sock, l);

    zmsg_t* msg;
    zframe_t *id;

    while (!zctx_interrupted)
    {       
        msg = zwssock_recv(sock);

        if (!msg)
            break;

        // first message is the routing id
        id = zmsg_pop(msg);

        while (zmsg_size(msg) != 0)
        {
            char * str = zmsg_popstr(msg);

            printf("%s\n", str);

            free(str);
        }

        zmsg_destroy(&msg);

        msg = zmsg_new();

        zmsg_push(msg, id);

        char buf[226] = { 10, 4, 78, 77, 69, 65, -110, 3, 19, 8, 101, -86, 6, 14, 8, 1, 16, -40, -126, -27, -14, -12,
            -87, -61, 2, -16, 1, 1, -110, 3, 93, 8, 100, 80, 0, -94, 6, 86, 34, 73, 36, 71, 80, 82,
            77, 67, 44, 49, 48, 51, 50, 51, 49, 46, 54, 48, 49, 44, 86, 44, 53, 50, 48, 53, 46, 54, 52, 50,
            54, 55, 48, 44, 78, 44, 48, 48, 54, 49, 57, 46, 54, 49, 51, 57, 52, 55, 44, 69, 44, 52, 51, 46,
            50, 44, 51, 54, 46, 52, 44, 50, 51, 48, 49, 49, 53, 4, 4, 44, 44, 83, 42, 54, 68, 32, 74, 9, 69, 80,
            83, 71, 58, 52, 51, 50, 54, -30, 3, 97, 10, 4, 78, 77, 69, 65, 18, 73, 36, 71, 80, 82, 77, 67, 44, 49,
            48, 51, 50, 51, 49, 46, 54, 48, 49, 44, 86, 44, 53, 50, 48, 53, 4, 6, 54, 52, 50, 54, 55, 48, 44, 78,
            44, 48, 48, 54, 49, 57, 46, 54, 49, 51, 57, 52, 55, 44, 69, 44, 52, 51, 46, 50, 44, 51, 54, 46, 52,
            44, 50, 51, 48, 49, 49, 53, 44, 44, 44, 83, 42, 54, 68, 32, 82, 14, 10, 5, 8, 2, -80, 1, 2, -94, 6, 4, 8, 8, 16, 6 };

        zmsg_addmem(msg, buf, 226);

        zwssock_send(sock, &msg);
    }

    zwssock_destroy(&sock);
    zctx_destroy(&ctx); 
}
```

and following javascript:

```
var dealer = new JSMQ.Dealer();
dealer.connect("ws://localhost:86");

// we must wait for the dealer to be connected before we can send messages, any messages we are trying to send
// while the dealer is not connected will be dropped
dealer.sendReady = function() {
    var message = new JSMQ.Message();
    message.addString("Hello");

    dealer.send(message);
};

dealer.onMessage = function (message) {
    // the response from the server
    var buffer = message.popBuffer();
    console.log(buffer.length);
    console.log(buffer);
};

function send() {
    var message = new JSMQ.Message();
    message.addString(document.getElementById("messageTextBox").value);

    dealer.send(message);
}
```